# Input dataframes aren't pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, generative-adversarial-network

I have borrow code from https://github.com/Diyago/GAN-for-tabular-data
The code states (after updates from below suggestions):

```
 def preprocess_data(self, train_df, target, test_df, ) -> Tuple[pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame,]:
    if isinstance(train_df, pd.DataFrame) is False or isinstance(target, pd.DataFrame) is False \
            or isinstance(test_df, pd.DataFrame) is False:
        raise ValueError("Input dataframes aren't pandas dataframes: train is {}; target is{} ; test is {}".
                         format(type(train_df), type(target), type(test_df)))
    self.TEMP_TARGET = target.columns[0]
    if self.TEMP_TARGET in train_df.columns:
        raise ValueError("Input train dataframe already have {} column, consider removing it".format(self.TEMP_TARGET))
    if "test_similarity" in train_df.columns:
        raise ValueError("Input train dataframe already have test_similarity, consider removing it")
```

I am getting `ValueError: Input dataframes aren't pandas dataframes: train is <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>; target is ; test is <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

So after comments below from @max I added pd.DataFrame, to the Tuple for test_df, but it makes no diffrence. Also I have added {} to line 4 "target is" BUT there is still no output in the answer.

The code for train and targit is:
`train=newDataFrame.iloc[:,0:-1]` 
`target=newDataFrame.iloc[:,-1]`

The newDataFrame is a cleaner version of the "adult dataset", that was loaded with normal `pd.read_csv`

I don't understand why they are not passed.

Comment: It is saying that `test_df` is a Series and not a DataFrame. You can try to pass `pd.DataFrame(test_df)`

Comment: Also, you're missing {} on line 4 after "target is", so you don't know in the error message if target is a dataframe or not.